# JavaFX - How to assign an Event Handle to an Array of Labels?

Tags: java, arrays, events, javafx, label

I am using Eclipse and Java (JavaFX)

I have a GridPane and an Array with Labels. I added to each row and column of the GridPane a Label.

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
Label lbs[] = new Label[20*20];
```

When i hover over a label, i want something to happend. Lets say the background should change.

If I had a single label without an array, it would work like this:

```
lbs.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
          @Override
          public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
              lbs.setStyle("-fx-background-color:BLACK;");

          }
        });
```

But since its an Array of Labels, it underlines the whole code block above in red and gives me this error message: 
**Cannot invoke setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler(){}) on the array type Label[]**

The only way it work is:

```
lbs[1].setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
      lbs[1].setStyle("-fx-background-color:BLACK;");

     }
   });
```

But I dnt wanna do it for all Labels. There should be a easier way i hope.

What should I do to make it work? I am new in this forum. My Prof suggested this to me and therefore I hope I added the codes here in a proper way.

Here is my whole code:

```
    package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

         Scene scene = new Scene(grid, (20 * 20), (20 * 20));
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    
        Label lbs[] = new Label[20*20];


        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);

         for (int i = 0; i < lbs.length; i++) {
                lbs[i]=new Label();
         }

         int count = 0;
         for (int x = 0; x < lbs.length/20; x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < lbs.length/20; y++){
                    grid.add(lbs[count], x, y);
                    count++;
                }
            }

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
ColumnConstraints column = new ColumnConstraints(20);
grid.getColumnConstraints().add(column);

}

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints(20);
grid.getRowConstraints().add(row);
}

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Here my CSS file, just in case it is important help solving this problem:

```
GridPane {
    -fx-background-color: white ;


    -fx-grid-lines-visible: true;
    -fx-border-color: black 
}

    Label {
          -fx-pref-height: 20;
              -fx-pref-width: 20;
        -fx-background-color: green ;
        -fx-font-size: 11pt;
        -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
        -fx-text-fill: Black;
        -fx-opacity: 0.6;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the handler on each label when you create it:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lbs.length; i++) {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setOnMouseEntered(e -> label.setStyle("-fx-background-color:BLACK;"));
        lbs[i]=label;
 }
```

If you end up with anything more complex, it probably helps to refactor the creation of the label into a separate method;

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < lbs.length; i++) {
    lbs[i] = createLabel(i);
}
```

and

```
private Label createLabel(int index) {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        // other things you need to do when the mouse hovers....
    });
    // other label configuration...
    return label ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. But does it mean I have to write all my codes inside this For loop? I am about to program a game like Minesweeper. So there will be some codings etc. Is it ok if I put all the codes inside this For Loop block? Or is there another way of doing it?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that question. You use a for loop for everything you have to do to each element of an array.

Comment: My bad. The question really wasnt clear enough. But now I know how to work this this code thanks to you and Arsenicum.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you. I just have another problem. How do I know which index the label of the array has when I hover over it with the mouse?

Comment: The index is `i`. So you can do `int index = i;` and access `index` in the handler.

Comment: I tried it that way but it wont let me. I will post the code here, even though it will look ugly:

   for (int i = 0; i < lbs.length; i++) {
       Label label = new Label();
       
       label.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
//               label.setStyle("-fx-background-color:BLACK;");
            if(lbs[i].getText().equals("X")) {
             label.setText("JA");
            }
            else label.setText("no");
           }
       });
       lbs[i] = label;
   }

Comment: Well that's not what I actually suggested, is it. Try it the way I suggested, or see the update to the answer.

Comment: THANK YOUUU. I just figured out what u suggested. works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Assign an Event Handle not to an Array of Labels but to every Label in that Array. Array is not GUI element so you can not hover it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbs.length; i++) {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color:BLACK;");
        }
    });
    lbs[i] = label;
}
```

Comment: Thank you alot. Now it easier for me to understand it :)